# How to use a defined mathematical function to create the U, V arguments in matplotlib.quiver()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a very basic model governing a falling object:

```
# ODE modelling velocity of a falling object
def field(t, v):
    v_dot = 9.8 - (gamma / mass) * v
    return v_dot
```

I have solved and plotted this ODE for a few different initial conditions. I would like to overlay the plot with a slope field using matplotlib.quiver().

I am specifically having a hard time sorting out the U, and V arguments. I understand that they are the x and y directions that each arrow is supposed to point.

Here is what I have tried, a tactic I gleaned from another answer:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 50, 6)
y = np.linspace(0, 150, 16)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
f = 9.8 - (gamma / mass) * Y
U, V = np.gradient(f)
Q = plt.quiver(X, Y, U, V)
```

However, this plots the following:

[image]

Which definitely wrong, not to mention ugly. It certainly seems that my main problem is that I do not know how to find U and V in a correct manner. I have browsed several other questions, but most people are doing something much more complex than I am, and I can't seem to scale down their answers to my more simple problem.

```
# ODE modelling velocity of a falling object
def field(t, v):
    v_dot = 9.8 - (gamma / mass) * v
    return v_dot

# gamma is the coefficient for air resistance
gamma = 0.392
mass = 3.2

# declare interval and step size
t_0 = 0.
t_n = 100.
delta = 0.05
time = np.arange(t_0, t_n, delta)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
fig.suptitle("A Simple Model: Falling Object")

axs.set_title(r"Solution to $\dot{v} = 9.8 - \frac{\gamma}{m}v$")
axs.set_ylabel('Velocity')
axs.set_xlabel('Time')

for x_0 in np.arange(0., 101., 20):
    # Solve for each initial condition x_0
    x = rk4(delta, time, field, x_0)

    # Plot results
    axs.plot(time, x, label=r"$v_0=$%.3f" % x_0)
```

Comment: This is not currently reproducible.  `def field` is not used, so why is it provided?  `gamma` and `mass` are missing.  Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney The full code is now available to you. However, this question was conceptual in nature. I am not looking for you to fix my code, but rather answer the question I asked. That question, for you again is this: How to use a defined mathematical function to create the U, V arguments in matplotlib.quiver()? My code snippets were simply an example for context.

Comment: `f = 9.8 - (gamma / mass) * Y;  U,V = np.gradient(f)`, Y is constant horizontally, so V is identically zero. What is your expectation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the commenters grasped that I needed help with the basic conceptual nature of the question. I understand that I am slow and stupid, and thankfully there are people outside of this forum who are more understanding of that. So here goes, with lots of comments in case someone who is as slow as I am ever needs help. Simply replace my ODE with whatever one you want to model, and play with the x and y axis arrays to get the spacing that you desire:

```
# ODE for falling object
def field(t, v):
    v_dot = 9.8 - (gamma / mass) * v
    return v_dot

# gamma is the coefficient for air resistance
gamma = 0.392
mass = 3.2

# x and y axis arrays 
x = np.linspace(0,50, 11) # time from zero to 50 inclusive
y = np.linspace(0,100, 11) # initial velocities from 0 to 100 inclusive

# meshgrid creates two arrays of shape(len(y), len(x))
# by pairing the values of these two arrays, we create a set
# of ordered pairs that give our coordinates for the location
# of the quiver arrows we wish to plot.
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# We know slope is v' = f(t, v), so we can use trig to get
# to the x and y components of our quiver arrow vectors
theta = np.arctan(field(X, Y))
U = np.cos(theta)
V = np.sin(theta)

plt.quiver(X, Y, U, V)

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```